# NDEF format for WiFI Pairing Data

Tags: wifi, nfc, ndef, lib-nfc

I have derived the WiFI Authentication and Encryption data format by writing it and then reading it from an application running on microcontroller.

Can some one please tell me the macros or values for the Authentication type `(WPA-Personel,Shared,WPA2-Enterprise,WpA2-Enterprise,WPA2-Personel)`fields and Encryption type fields `(None,WEP,TKIP,ES,AES/TKIP)`.

I have figured out for WPA/WPA2-Personel authentication type and AES encryption type so far as below .

```
52  0x10 0x03   2   Attribute ID: Authentication Type 
54  0x00 0x02   2   Attribute Length: 2 octets
56  0x00 0x20   2   Authentication Type: WPA2-Personal
58  0x10 0x0F   2   Attribute ID: Encryption Type 
60  0x00 0x02   2   Attribute Length: 2 octets
62  0x00 0x08   2   Encryption Type: AES
```

Any official documentation will be highly appreciated.